# Ячейки в StringGrid

Tags: c++builder

При нажатии на ячейку закрашиваю её в зелёный

```
if(State.Contains(gdSelected))
{
    StringGrid1->Canvas->Brush->Color = COLOR_TRUE;
    StringGrid1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
}
```

Как при повторном нажатии на ячейку закрасить её в другой цвет?
И как можно убрать цвет заливки?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы объявил enum - цвет ячейки. И создал бы матрицу этих флагов для всех ячеек грида. И при щелчке анализировал бы ее и изменял нужным образом.